# character array to string in C?

Tags: c, string

I want to turn an array of characters into ONE string.

Example:

`char foo[2] = {'5', '0'};` --> `char* foo = "50";`

What would be the best way to go about doing this in C? The problem stems from a larger problem I'm having trying to extract a substring from command line input.  For example, I want to make `argv[1][0]` and `argv[1][1]` into ONE string so that if the program was run like this...

```
$ ./foo 123456789
```

I could assign "12" to a `char*` variable.

Comment: Is `{"5", "0"}` meant to be `{'5', '0'}` or is `char foo[2]` meant to be `char *foo[2]` ?

Comment: the former case...the array is of two individual chars.

Comment: @InternetSeriousBusiness, b/c the user of this particular program need not be concerned with the splitting of the first two characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
char* foo_as_str = malloc(3);
memset(foo_as_str, 0, 3);
strncpy(foo_as_str, argv[1], 2);
```

Comment: thanks to all who answered (this one worked very easily), I've definitely got some research to do on the methods presented.

Comment: @beProactive, be aware this example has a bug: `strncpy` doesn't guarantee a null terminated string.

Comment: `memset` is a bit of overkill, you could have just done `foo_as_str[2] = 0`. `strncpy` *will* null terminate the whole buffer if the string is shorter than the count.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite your example since you can't initialize a `char[]` with multiple literal strings:

```
char foo[3] = { '5', '0', '\0' }; // now foo is the string "50";
```

Note that you need at least *3* elements in your array if `foo` is to hold the string `"50"`: the additional element is for the null-terminating character, which is required in C strings.
We
The above is equivalent to:

```
char foo[3] = "50";
```

But you don't need this to extract the first two characters from `argv[1]`, you can use [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy):

```
char foo[3];
foo[0] = '\0';

if ((argc > 1) && (strlen(argv[1]) >= 2)
{
    // this copies the first 2 chars from argv[1] into foo
    strncpy(foo, argv[1], 2);
    foo[2] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: You have also fallen for the `strncpy` trap, it does not guarantee to null terminate the string. In your case it's easy to fix, just initialize `foo` to zeros with `char foo[3] = {0};`

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm guilty. thanks for catching that.  I really need to start writing unit tests for my SO answers

Answer (score 2):

Check out the man page of [strcat](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/strcat.html). Mind overwriting constant strings.

If you want just put chars together to form a string, let you do that as well:

```
char foo[3];
foo[0] = '1';
foo[1] = '2';
foo[2] = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

To make a string you will need to add a null terminating byte after the two characters. This means that the memory address following them needs to be under your control so that you can write to it without messing up anyone else. In this case, to do that you will need to allocate some additional memory for the string:

```
int length = 2; // # characters
char* buffer = malloc(length + 1); // +1 byte for null terminator
memcpy(buffer, foo, length); // copy digits to buffer
buffer[length] = 0; // add null terminating byte

printf("%s", buffer); // see the result
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strcat` although you must ensure that the destination buffer is large enough to accomodate the resultant string.

Answer (score 0):

Try by using `strcat()`.

```
  char *foo[2] = {"5", "0"}; /* not the change from foo[x] to *foo[x] */ 
  size_t size = sizeof(foo) / sizeof(foo[0]);
  char *buf = calloc(sizeof(char), size + 1);
    if(buf) {
      int i;
      for(i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    strcat(buf, foo[i]);
      printf("buf = [%s]\n", buf);
    } else {
      /* NO momeory. handling error. */
    }
```

Output:

```
buf = [50]
```